# Want to convert time to minutes -> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a code to convert a column I have that contains time written in this format '36:21' which I am trying to convert to h, m, s format.

```
time_list = df7[' Chip Time'].tolist()
time_mins = []
for i in time_list:
    h, m, s = i.split(':')
    math = (int(h) * 3600 + int(m) * 60 + int(s))/60
    time_mins.append(math)
#print(time_mins)
```

I keep receiving this error whenever I run the code

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [43], in <cell line: 6>()
      5 time_mins = []
      6 for i in time_list:
----> 7     h, m, s = i.split(':')
      8     math = (int(h) * 3600 + int(m) * 60 + int(s))/60
      9     time_mins.append(math)

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

Comment: What would you expect the values of `h`, `m`, and `s` to be from `36:21`?

Comment: please provide an example of `time_list`.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I would expect the values to be 00:36:21 
@PeterWood

Comment: @D.L I want time_list to be converted to this format 00:36:21

Comment: "I would expect the values to be 00:36:21" That's not how `split()` works. I suggest you read the documentation for `split()`.

Comment: @RiyatLikita why would it be that?

Comment: @PeterWood Sorry, I meant I would like it in this format 36.3500 or 37.733

Answer (score 1):

You wrote that in this column it is given as XX:YY. So if you do `split(":")` you will get two values not three. If they are hours and minutes then you are missing seconds which is why you have the error.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access three values from a list of two.
You are splitting the value `36:21` by `:`, which gives you `['36', '21']`.  This has a length of two.  However, you are trying to set three values (`h`, `m`, and `s`) to these two values, hence the error.

If you want to remove the `h` value, try removing the `h,` , changing the line to:

```py
m, s = i.split(':')
```

You will then have to update the following lines accordingly.
Alternatively, if you want to leave the lines after it the same, you could define `h` as 0.

You can also follow that same process if you want to get rid of a different value (`m` or `s`) instead of `h`.

Comment: Currently it is written in m:s so I am trying to get hours from that.

Comment: @RiyatLikita Fixed to match that

Comment: @RiyatLikita If you have `m:s` as the format, then hours is automatically `0`. There's no need to get it from the `split()`.